# How to clone a read-only portion of /proc file system

Tags: linux, scripting, file-copy, proc, safecopy

The problem with reading /proc file system is that it is not atomic. I tried using a library (procfs in Python) that wishes to read it, but it has glitches about 5% of the time because the process that I am after is now gone. So, I wish to copy everything in /proc to another location, say `/proc_clone/<GUID>/`. A GUID can be generated using the `uuidgen` command.

The naive approach would be trying to use `cp -r`, but I am getting a whole bunch of 'permission denied' errors and it is taking more than a second. I am only after a subset `/proc/<pid>` and even then, only the read-only stuff that can be turned into a string (ultimately I wish to build a single JSON file that contains all of this).

I am looking for a script that would do that for me and is also short, simple, very fast, **can deal with processes dying mid-flight by skipping them**, however, I would like to avoid writing C code - I would much rather stick to bash, existing utilities and maybe Perl / Python. The goal here is just to take a snapshot of a subset of `/proc`, not produce the JSON file itself.

I have heard opinions that "one should not ever try to copy `/proc` but just read from it". Well, the non-atomic nature of it means that one has to throw a bunch of `try/catch` all over the code when trying to do very simple operations. Using a high level language like Python (what I ultimately want to use) to iterate over `/proc` is a slow method, which involves both IO and CPU time. This increases the risk of seeing a process die on you (I certainly see it often; I have a script that interrogates /proc every minute and I run into plenty of exceptions). I would like to build a library that outputs a single JSON file that contains cpu and memory usage information about processes in a human-readable format (e.g. using seconds and not jiffies, bytes and not pages, have units in addition to values. I am not concerned that it would take some time to create that file out of a directory dump; I just want to make sure that the snapshot is as accurate as possible. So. if I should not just copy /proc over, then which other method should I use?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Copying a complete process _will_ take a lot of time...

Comment: @vonbrand, I believe I stated what I want to do. Say I want to copy reliably and fast all of the `/proc/*/cmdline` and all of the `/proc/*/statm` and `/proc/*/status` files. Can you suggest a tool/script that can do that for me?

Comment: I understand the problem. But why can't you catch the exception where the file being read is gone (and terminate whatever you wanted to do there)?

Comment: @Nils, A) Because I want to minimize the window during which I interact with the `/proc` file system, B) Initially I was using a nice high-level library for Python called `procfs`. I would prefer to use that library, except hack it to point to a new root.

Comment: So you should catch the exception. I looked into some mount-options (`mount --make-private`) that looked as if you could do a snapshot of a FS-mount, but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a look at the [man pages for proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Look at `/proc/[pid]/*`
entries and pick which files you want.

You do **not** want to copy everything. As an example you have 
`/proc/[pid]/mem` which is all the virtual memory for a process including
shared etc. – i.e. size of all your memory. Further you are not able to read it unless the process own `mem` or it is `ptraced` and read with higher privileges. (And then *only* Virtual Size - `/proc/pid/status -> VmSize`) – and so on.

Or `/proc/PID/exe` which simply is a link to the executable, `/proc/PID/fd/*` which holds file descriptors for `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` and other files, 
pipes etc.

There is a lot of other *special* files as well, and a lot of links (If you were to follow them all you'll never be done). Read the man mentioned above, [documentation from kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt), etc.

---

Further the files are not block-device files. They reside in memory as proc is
a memory based filesystem. In one way you can call it a window into the kernel
arranged for easy access.

Thus this is also a big advantage when it comes to the reads it looks like you
want – as the information reside in memory there is no disk I/O and therefore
very fast. Off course if you choose to write the data to disk this is lost –
but is still much faster then disk to disk.

---

Look at it as shared memory and try to not duplicate more then necessary. 
For your task you would probably also look at files at the root level of
`/proc`. Look at the source code for `ps`, `top`, `free` etc. to get a quick
introduction to how other tools do it.

---

Have written a few other answers that might more or less touch some of the
aspects. You might find some of it useful:

- [Top and ps not showing the same cpu result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58539/top-and-ps-not-showing-the-same-cpu-result/58541#58541)
- [htop reporting much higher memory usage than free or top](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65835/htop-reporting-much-higher-memory-usage-than-free-or-top/65852#65852)
- [Why does rsync fail to copy files from /sys in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73569/why-does-rsync-fail-to-copy-files-from-sys-in-linux/73610#73610)

---

***Edit:***

As for comment. You could do something like:

```
save_to=/some/path

pushd /proc
for d in [0-9]*; do
    cp "$d/cmdline" "$save_to/$d.cmdline"
    cp "$d/status" "$save_to/$d.status"
done
popd
```

But I would have used some lower level like e.g. C to parse the files as the
method above quite possible not would be quick enough for what one want.

If it is a one time copy every hour or so, OK, but not for e.g. seconds or even
a few minutes interval.

Comment: so say I want to copy over only `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`, `/proc/<pid>/statm`, `/proc/<pid?/status` reliably and fast. Is there a command-line utility that would help me do that?